# Self Contained installation luarocks on Windows

Tags: lua, installation, self-contained, luarocks

I want to create self contained installation with luarocks that contain lua installation plus some lua and Dll files I added to the library.

In other word I have one lua appender that I want to add to the logging folder, and two dll files that I want to add to lua Clibs.

I looked to the luarocks documentation I couldn't find how I can do this part

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The install script for the current LuaRocks version (2.2.0) has a `/SELFCONTAINED` option (`/FORCECONFIG` might also be of interest, and you probably want to remove the "user" tree from `config.lua`).

Where you put your extra library files has nothing to do with LuaRocks. As long as the Lua binary can find them, everything is ok. The default `package.path` contains the directory of the Lua executable, so this would be a reasonable place to put your extra files (don't forget the necessary subdirectories, e.g. `logging`).

Comment: Ok I did set SELFCONTAINED and FOCERCONFIG to true, I couldn't find Config.lua. When I try to run the luaRocks from the command line using "install /p c:\users\public\lua\LuaRocks /MW" i get Lua Interpreter not found. Do I need to install a lua interpreter first or it is available with version 2.2.0-win32??

Comment: @jprbest: LuaRocks for Windows comes with Lua 5.1 binaries. Use the `/L` commandline switch to use those. If you need a different Lua version, you will have to install/build Lua first. When you (successfully) run the install script, it will tell you where `config.lua` is located.

Comment: Thanks it works, the only issue I'm getting is if I tried to create a subdirectories eq in my case logging folder it won't created after I install luaRocks

Comment: @jprbest: What doesn't work? You can't create the subdirectories, or Lua won't find the extra modules in the created subdirectories?